# Prove about small O

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Prove the equivalence of the following expressions

1. $\left\|\left(\nabla^2 (_)−_\right)(_{+1}−_)\right\|=o\left(\left\|_{+1}−_\right\|\right)$.

2.$\left\|\nabla(_{+1})−\nabla (_)−_(_{+1}−_)\right\|=o\left(\left\|_{+1}−_\right\|\right).$

I never work with small or if someone can help me with a hint i appreciate.

Where $x_{k+1}=x_k+\alpha p_k$ where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $p$ is a descent direction and $H_k$ is a matrix how approaches the Hessian, I traid to use the limit definition on Hessian matrix size i have $\lim_{\alpha  \longrightarrow 0 } \dfrac{\nabla(_{+1})−\nabla (_)}{\beta}$ if i remplace on 1

1. $\left\|\left(\lim_{\alpha \longrightarrow 0 } \dfrac{\nabla(_{+1})−\nabla (_)}{\alpha}−_\right)(_{+1}−_)\right\|=o\left(\left\|_{+1}−_\right\|\right)$.

Here is close of what i need but i dont see how to continue.

Comment: When people say "small O" they usually use lower case $o(\,)$ in contrast to "big O" $O(\,)$, rather than using really small $ℴ(\,)$

Comment: You should define $x_k, H_k$. and mention that $\nabla$ is a forward difference, not a divergence (if it is).  Or maybe it is a divergence and the $x_k$ are steps in an iteration converging to something.  Then problems without context are discouraged.  What have you tried?

Comment: i try to fix thx for the comments

Comment: **Hint**: you can use the following identity, which follows from the Taylor theorem:

$$
\nabla f(y) = \nabla f(x) + \nabla^2 f(x)(y - x) + o\left(\| x - y \|\right).
$$

Comment: i can do it thx for the hint